# Cannot call another class method inside the servlet when using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Im trying to send data from jsp to servlet in jquery ajax,

this should happen when a button is pressed.(button id = "btnadd")

The script code ::

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#btnadd').click(function(){  
            $.ajax({  
                url : 'AdminOperation',  
                type : 'POST',  
                data : {  
                    bname : $('#bname').val(),  
                    bauthor : $('#bauthor').val(),  
                    noOfBooks : $('#noOfBooks').val(),  
                    fn_name : 'addBook'  
                },  
                success : function(responseText){  
                    $('#dispArea').text(responseText);  
                }  
            });  
        });  
    });
```

Servlet Code :

```
 public void addBookFN(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException
{
    String bname = request.getParameter("bname");
    String bauthor = request.getParameter("bauthor");
    int noOfBooks = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noOfBooks"));

    int flag = 0;

    AdminHandler aobj = new AdminHandler();
    flag = aobj.addBook(bname, bauthor, noOfBooks);
    String data;
    if(flag==1)
        data = "Success";
    else
        data="Failure";
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(data);
}
```

This above funtion is called if the fn_name is addBook.
Im calling another function from here.

The code worked fine when i did it without using ajax(sending data when the form is submitted to the Servlet)
But reports the error when with JQuery AJAX.

Error ::
    Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()

Note:: All the other function without AJAX works fine.

Update:: The error doesnt seems to be sending, But when trying to call method addBook.
If there is no call, The Code works fine..

addBook method ::

```
public int addBook(String name, String author, int noOfBooks)
{
    JSONObject addBJO = new JSONObject();
    addBJO.put("name",name);
    addBJO.put("author",author);
    addBJO.put("noOfBooks",noOfBooks);
    int flag = addBookCpp(addBJO);
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: then use addBook in url

Comment: i dont get it, i must call the servlet..

Comment: @SivaRahul `AdminOperation` this should be your servlet class name

Comment: Post your full `error` message .

Comment: ive edited the question, it dooesnt seems to be in the sending part,, but it is in calling the addBook method,, help me please

Comment: @dheerajkumar, ive used url-mapping for the servlet and it is AdminOperation

Comment: post `addbook` method

Comment: @Swati i cant understand

Comment: What does `addBookCpp` do  in above method ?

Comment: @Swati it is JNI native method which adds the record to the file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in the above code.
The error was actually in the Native Library.